# React Native ios: cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again

Tags: react-native

Hello i am new to react native...
i want to try out my app on my iphone ...
as we know xcode 8 creates bundle identifier automatically(when we create an app through xcode..not react native)
it seems in  react native, that we need to change it
how can i do that?

Comment: I also have this question. Did you learn anything Sam?

Comment: yes...you can change it in xcode

Comment: but for now...we can't change through react

Comment: Thanks very much Sam for that info, so it is safe to change the bundle identifier in xcode. Thanks for that info I was scared to change it as i thought it would break. And I needed to change it for the release to app store.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. How can we change the bundle id. Is this cause any problems?@Sam @Noitidart

Comment: @Jes you can change the bundle id in xcode. No problems with changing it.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add an account under Preferences->Accounts, than set your own Product Bundle Identifier(the default one you created with reactnative is com.reactjs.native.example.****). it works for me

Comment: I can't able to run my app. It showing the error which I mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299672/how-to-clone-a-project-in-xcode-and-run-the-app-in-the-ios-7-or-7-etc. But the above solution doesn't resolved my issue

Comment: I can able to run my app by changing the bundle id.