# How to clone a project in xcode and run the app in the ios 7, or 7+, etc

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile

I have cloned a project and tried to run my app on a device(iPhone 7), but it showing the build failure with the below-mentioned error.

Note: If I create a new project in Xcode then, I can able to run the app on my device.

How can I solve this?

## Error:

```
Failed to create provisioning profile.


     The app ID "org.reactjs.native.example.app" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.


        No profiles for 'org.reactjs.native.example.app' were found
        Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'org.reactjs.native.example.app'.
```

Comment: It clearly shows that the developer account in the apple doesnot have the provisioning profile associated with the particular bundle id for the ios application and for the particular bundle id mentioned by you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Error signing Failed to create provisioning profile and No profiles for 'com.photo.appwall' were found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906399/xcode-error-signing-failed-to-create-provisioning-profile-and-no-profiles-for-c)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have a valid iTunes Connect developer account:

App IDs are unique per all App Store accounts. Therefore if someone had registered an appId of `org.reactjs.native.example.app` as it is in your case, you cannot use it. That was clearly used by react.js guys and is now part of their profile(s). You need to change the appId of the cloned project to something unique. Most common notation used is `com.my_organization_name.my_project_name`. You can also go for prefixing the original id with lets say `com.my_organization.tests.org.reactjs.native.example.app` or something similar